# Nginx Ingress IP Pending on Ubuntu Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rancher, nginx-ingress

We have a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 18.04.1.0.
We have used [this](https://itnext.io/tutorial-part-1-kubernetes-up-and-running-on-lxc-lxd-b760c79cd53f) tutorial to install lxd and we have used [this](https://itnext.io/tutorial-part-2-kubernetes-up-and-running-on-lxc-lxd-6d60e98f22df) tutorial to install kubernetes.

Now we want to install Rancher regarding [this](https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-05-18-how-to-run-rancher-2-0-on-your-desktop/) tutorial (it works fine on Docker for Desktop on Windows) on this ubuntu machine.

The problem is: we stuck on the `nginx-ingress` part. Nginx does not get any IP, state will be `pending` forever.
I already tried to `set rbac.create=true` (which is already set in the helm chart defaults); but I cannot figure out what's wrong here and why the `nginx-ingress` does not get any IP on the ubuntu kubernetes cluster.

What we have missed?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to watch logs from pod?

Comment: Rancher has been tested with various official versions of Docker but not with LXD. You might want to file an enhancement request or upvote one if there is already one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at [Here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/).
I think you should change service type of nginx-ingress-controller service to `NodePort` to solve the pending problem. As default nginx-ingress-controller service type is `Loadbalancer` and you have to have an external load balancer to use this type of service. on Cloud Providers like AWS or GKE it is OK but on bare metal you have to use other types of services like `NodePort`.
Also if you use `NodePort` and you need to serve on port 80/443 you will need a reverse proxy out of your cluster.

Comment: Thanks, I already did the stuff with the NodePort (didnt say that here to proof that I was right). But okay... then the reverse proxy is missing. This means Kubernetes on Docker for Windows already has this reverse proxy, but on the Ubuntu machine I have to set up one by myself... I already saw your link but there was no hint (so far?) that shows the stuff of a reverse proxy. Is it possible to use the same nginx as ingress and reverse proxy to save ressources on my metal or whats the best practise here?

Comment: Suppose your cluster is a Black Box and you can access that Black Box using the `NodePort` assigned to your nginx-ingress-controller service. you need an nginx out of your cluster to proxy requests to your cluster on the `NodePort`.

Comment: Thanks. We decided to use traefik and pass an external IP. Traefik acts as our reverse proxy pretty fine!